# The distribution Django project runs different with the local project, get 1366, "Incorrect string value Error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The distribution Django project runs different with the local project.
I have a Django project, in it there is a create APIView, in my local repo, it works fine, but when I push the repo to the remote, then run it with

`screen -d -m python3 -m Qy.wsgi`

and if I access the create url, there comes the `500 Server Error` error.

but in my local repo, it works fine.

related code are bellow:

model:

```
class Currency(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    standard_symbol = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    ex_rate = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, default=0.0000, max_digits=10)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-standard_symbol']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

apiview:

```
class CurrencyCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = CurrencySerializer
    permission_classes = [IsSuperAdminOrFinanceAdmin]
    queryset = Currency.objects.all()
```

serializer:

```
 class CurrencySerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Currency
        fields = "__all__"
```

I just don't know why in the distribution it can not create with Chinese characters.

I means if I write in all number, such as:

`name: 123, desc: 123, standard_symbol: 123, ex_rate:1233`

it will create success.

or if there is English Characters it will works too, but if there is Chinese Character it will report the `500 Server Error`. I use MySQL as database.

but in the local repo it will works if it contains Chinese Characters.

the remote repo code is as same as the local repo.

My local repo operation system: `MacOS`
My remote repo operation system: `CentOS7.2`

---

**EDIT-1**

My settings of `wsgi.py` is bellow:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "qy.settings")

import django

print("django.setup()")
django.setup()

from socketio import Middleware
from qysio.views import sio

django_app = get_wsgi_application()
application = Middleware(sio, django_app)



import eventlet
import eventlet.wsgi
eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), application)
```

---

**EDIT-2**

I set the `DEBUG=True` in settings.py, and I get the bellow error when edit(the same as use create ):

```
OperationalError at /api/productconfig/price_system/currency/1/edit/
(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE4\\xBA\\xBA\\xE6\\xB0\\x91...' for column 'name' at row 1")
```

Comment: You will have to find the error traceback and post it here. Where it is depends on your WSGI setup.

Comment: Why would you run a server like that? Your speed to run it with a wsgi server like gunicorn or u.

Comment: @DanielRoseman See my EDIT-1.

Comment: @KlausD. See my EDIT-2. bro.

Answer (score 0):

I see your Error `1366, "Incorrect string value:`.

There is a famous error of charset error.

So, make sure of your database and table use `utf-8` character set.

you can use

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE your_database_name;
ALTER DATABASE your_database_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

check and alter the database character set.

use bellow for check and alter character set of table:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name;
ALTER TABLE your_table_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

and change your table field character set:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table_name` CHANGE `table_field` `table_field ` VARCHAR( 45 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
```

Comment: Also make sure all your components use UTF-8: database, Django, and the rendered HTML including forms.